# Password not working in Graphical Applications (gksu)? Works with sudo

Tags: sudo, gksu, password

I am having a problem where when I try to run say GParted, when I am prompted for a password, it says "Incorrect Password"

But when I enter the same password using terminal `sudo gparted` for example, it works. Why is that?

**UPDATE**

I noticed that theres a difference between using `sudo` and `gksu`. The later will fail with incorrect password ...

Comment: Do you have a different keyboard layout in the terminal? Test by typing in a text editor both in terminal and in gui.

Comment: Are you using LDAP, Active Directory, Samba, bluetooth, smart card, or any other password authentication methods, or is this simply a standalone computer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried `gksudo`? I've actually never seen `gksu` before.

From https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-studio-users/2007-September/000472.html:

`gksu` is a frontend to `su`, and `gksudo` is a frontend to `sudo`.

So if `sudo` is working properly for you, `gksudo` and *not* `gksu` is the graphical extension of `sudo` when you need to gain administrative privileges without using the terminal.

Comment: Actually, gksu is a frontend for both gksu and gksudo (see http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/gksu.1.html, Description, paragraph 3). While there is nothing wrong with using gksudo, gksu is the standard way to run graphical programs as root on Ubuntu (even though sudo, and not su, is used), and many graphical programs install menu items that use gksu. In a properly working Ubuntu system, gksu is set is sudo rather than su mode. Thus, desgua's post about setting the authentication mode to "sudo" in gksu-properties is really the correct answer to this question.

Answer (score 22):

Open gksu-properties (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gksu-properties`).
Then make sure the Authentication mode is set for "sudo".

[image]

Reference: [1](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1424299).

Comment: Indeed, gksu is a frontend to both sudo and su, and when a sudo-using OS like Ubuntu has working gksudo and broken gksu, it is almost always because the authentication mode is incorrectly set to su. Since sudo-mode=true in a correctly configured Ubuntu system, this problem is at least sometimes and perhaps always due to a bug. If this has always happened since installation and the system was created from a command-line only system, then this is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gksu/+bug/685349 (you can use the green "This bug affects..." link to indicate it affects you).

Comment: Learning something new every day. Thanks for the info!