# My password not accepted by applications

Tags: password

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 using mini.iso
And I installed Gnome 3, and bleachbit and remastersys etc.
When I open these applications from Menu, and it ask for password.
I entered password and it does not accepting and says "Incorrect password".
But, I could enter password through Terminal and run above mentioned applications.
How can I bypass the problem?

Comment: I got the solution from here
http://askubuntu.com/questions/48215/password-not-working-in-graphical-applications-gksu-works-with-sudo?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem now it's ok

run the command gksu-properties and change the "Authentication mode" to "sudo" and close. Now do gksu bleachbit, or whatever GUI application you want to run as root, and type your password (the one you use for updating and installing)