# Nemo, open as root, Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, root, nemo

I replaced nautilus with nemo in Ubuntu 13.04 from these excellent instructions:

[How to completely remove Unity, and replace it with Cinnamon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292394/how-to-completely-remove-unity-and-replace-it-with-cinnamon)

However, I can't "open folder as root" from Nemo. Know what I can check? Everything else seems to work great.

Got closer, I installed gksu, and it prompted me for the password, however it wouldn't accept it and could not open. Seems like I'm missing something in my nemo install. Maybe I'll try reinstalling. ( did that, no change )

nemo seems to be using gksu, not gksudo ... I can simulate it from the command line. Not sure how to tell it to use gksudo instead for "open as root".  Pretty sure that's the problem, as I can tell by the password dialog that gksu is being run instead of gksudo.

Comment: whats is the difference it makes to start from terminal with sudo? Afterall you run it as a root very seldom!

Comment: ha, nothing much.  just lazy i suppose!  ( more steps ...although generally i do have a terminal open )

Comment: If that is the case I have put an answer for you!

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

```
gksudo nemo
```

Enter password
Done!

If you are too lazy leave terminal open and just use Up/Down buttons to select command and Enter to shoot it!

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the fact that gksu doesn't work as expected in the 64-bit version of Ubuntu 13.04.

[This answer shows how to fix it](https://askubuntu.com/a/57452)

After installing gksu with `sudo apt-get install gksu`, type in terminal `gksu-properties` and set authentication mode to **sudo**. That will make "open as root" work in nemo.

Answer (score 1):

```
gksudo nemo / -w
```

-w to exit terminal after authentication or cancel

you can use it with ***launcher***

Answer (score 0):

Available also in Ubuntu 20.04, KDE neon ... :
In a terminal enter (without sudo, i.e. without root rights) :
`xhost +`

It's done! After that, '*open as root*' should work.