# Why won't my password work in gksu?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, password, gksu

There are other questions similar, but none have answers for this situation.

Any time I enter my pw into the terminal, it works fine.  But gsku thinks it's wrong.  I've tried several times, and typing very slowly.  I know I'm entering it correctly.  Any ideas?

---

Answers to questions:

- The answer linked doesn't apply because the gksu properties are set correctly.
- Resetting the pw didn't help.
- I was referring to the 10-key pad.

Comment: Are there any non-standard characters? These might be interpreted differently by sudo and a graphical application program.

Comment: @ sudodus No, only numbers.  I've tried using the 10-key and the standard keys.

Comment: Is it only `gksu` or does `sudo` also think it's wrong?

Comment: What is the 10-key? Do you mean F10?

Comment: Does [desgua's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/57452) to [Password not working in Graphical Applications (gksu)? Works with sudo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48215/password-not-working-in-graphical-applications-gksu-works-with-sudo/57452) help? You've said similar questions haven't helped you--can you give specific details about the other things you've found, why they're inapplicable, everything you have tried, and exactly what happened? How are you running gksu? You can [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/866562/edit) to add this and any other possibly relevant information.

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate. The item you've linked to doesn't answer the question either.

Answer (score -1):

**tl;dr**: Try using `gksudo` instead.

#### Explanation

`gksu` makes you enter the root password. By default, Ubuntu does not have a password for the `root` user. `gksudo` makes you enter the password for an ordinary user that happens to have superuser privileges.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, in Ubuntu `gksu` is an alias of `gksudo`, as the `root` password is not set by default. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/21033/what-is-the-difference-between-gksudo-and-gksu

Comment: @user68186 `gksu` and `gksudo` don't *always* act the same way on Ubuntu. Neither is an alias of the other, but it's true `gksudo` is a symbolic link to `gksu`, so the same executable runs whichever one is used. But [that executable actually checks the name that was used to invoke it, and may behave differently depending on how the user has configured it](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/gksu.1.html). `gksu` *should* behave the same way as `gksudo` on Ubuntu, but unfortunately this seems to depend on how it was installed (not all Ubuntu flavors preinstall `gksu` and `gkudo`).